# Kernel panic: "initramfs unpacking failed"

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

[image: screenshot]

What's wrong here?  How do I fix this?

Comment: As stated by the kernel panic, the [Initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs) can't be unpacked. This is most likely due to a faulty kernel update. Try to boot a previous kernel, and reinstall the kernel update.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You had this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but the screenshot shows that you are running VirtualBox, not WSL.  I've updated the tags for you.  Thanks!

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, only a Lubuntu tag. Was the system cleanly shutdown during the last session?  If it wasn't then I'd have booted *live* media & performed file-system checks to check for any corruption due to unclean shutdown & then expect normal booting next time. Was the system changed in the last session etc.......   I'd look for clues in the last session & what was done there, but you gave no specific details, no release details etc.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Nah, it was just not enough memory to unpack the kernel. As stated in the answer below you need to set enough RAM to the virtual machine.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem while trying to install Ubuntu 22.04, happen that I did not respect the [Recommended system requirements](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop):

2 GHz dual-core processor or better 4 GB system memory 25 GB of free hard drive space...

adjusting the RAM to 2048MB fixed it!